# Shipping details not showing after form filled up in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, usps

I have used USPS shipping method in woocommerce.

As a guest user when I go to checkout page in **Your Order** section shipping method says **Please fill in your details to see available shipping methods.**

When I filled all details it will not shown the details. If I refresh the page it will show but after filling form details its not shown.

I want after filling up billing details and shipping details.

Can someone give any advice?

Comment: most likely that plugin was not updated with latest version of woocommerce or there is some compatibility issue with your theme with woocommerce, contact author of corresponding plugin/theme they will guide to get it done.

Comment: @Vignesh I have updated plugins but  still I don't see shipping method.

Comment: Did you checked by changing different theme? As it is nothing to do with programming, is more like troubleshooting. Hence contact plugin author and let them know about your problem and they have a better solution to solve your queries. Also specify plugin url because there are many plugins available in wordpress

Comment: Try to figure out first where is the problem is it either from theme or plugin? And then it will be easy to troubleshoot